# Remove all instances of a movie clip from stage AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, children

I am trying to have some dots follow my cursor but I can't delete the old dots so all that ends up happening is I get a lot of dots on a grid. I've tried removeChild and some other methods but none of them work.
Theres 2 parts to this code because I was hoping to alternate between them so one could delete/remove the other while it was running. All of this is contained within a timer that runs every half second.

```
if(radius<8 && counter%2!=0){
    xCoord = ((radius*Math.cos(theta))*25)+275;
    yCoord = ((radius*Math.sin(theta))*(-1)*25)+225;
    for(dots = 1; dots<=ship; dots++){
        var dotInstance2:dot = new dot();
        dotSprite2.addChild(dotInstance2);
        mcArray2.push(dotInstance2);
        dotInstance2.x=xCoord;
        dotInstance2.y=yCoord;
        xCoord = ((xCoord-275)/25);
        yCoord = ((yCoord-225)/25)*(-1);
        theta = Math.atan(yCoord/xCoord)-(15*(Math.PI/180));
        if(xCoord<0){
            theta = theta + Math.PI;
        }
        xCoord = ((radius*Math.cos(theta))*25)+275;
        yCoord = ((radius*Math.sin(theta))*(-1)*25)+225;
    }
}
```

The dots are supposed to snap to a polar grid (which I already have done and that works) I just need to be able to delete the old dots after there are more than "ship" (a number) dots on the stage.

There are no test ways of removing the instances in this code because none of them worked.
What I have tried is adding the instances to an array and removing all the values from the array, using removeChild and removeChildAt, also trying to remove the sprites I have (dotSprite2 in this example)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDots(num:Number){
  for (var i:int=0; i<num; i++){        
    var dotInst:dot = mcArray2.shift();
    dotSprite2.removeChild(dotInst);
  }
}
```

This should work. If not, seems there are any references/listeners on the dot,
you didn't show them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the dots into an array is the correct way, I would do it like this

```
var dots:Array = new Array() //your array that holds dots
var dotsSprite:Sprite = new Sprite() //the sprite that holds the dots in its displaylist
addChild(dotsSprite);

//when you create your dots
var dot = new dot();
dots.push(dot);
dotsSprite.addChild(dot);

//to destroy the first dot in your array (the oldest dot)
dotsSprite.removeChild(dots.shift());
```

the `shift()` method of arrays removes the first entry in the array and shifts the others one step to the left (so position 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1 etc.). It also return the object in question, so we can pass it right to `dotsSprite.removeChild()` as a parameter, so it will be removed from its parents displaylist.

You weren't really clear in your question, so I assume you didn't try to remove the child from your `dotsSprite2`, instead you tried to remove it from whereever your code was running with `removeChild((the dot))`.

Essentially, your timer method should be something like this

```
function tick(e:TimerEvent):void{
    //this is the event listener for the timer you mentioned
    //first we should check if there are old dots already on the stage
    //we can set the amount of old dots that should stay before they're removed
    if(dots.length>(amount of old dots you want to stay){
        //remove a dot in this timer tick
        dotsSprite.removeChild(dots.shift());
    }

    //then create a new dot, unless one at the current location already exists
}
```

This could still be improved, for example you could define a lifecycle for the dots, the amount of time one dot can be on the stage. For this, I would recommend something like this:

In your Class that creates and destroys the dots

```
const dot_life_time:int = 3000; //3000ms = 3s
```

In your Dot Class

```
public var created:int = 0;
```

When you create your Dots, give them the current running time of your swf (in milliseconds) through the getTimer() method of Flash

```
//the dot creation part comes here
dot.created = getTimer();
//add it to the sprite and array
```

Now, instead of checking if the array is over a specific length, you should go through each dot in the array and check if its time is over

```
function tick(e:TimerEvent):void{
    for(var i:int=0;i<dots.length;i++){
        var elapsed:int = getTimer() - dots[i].created;
        if(elapsed >= dot_life_time){
            //destroy the dot
        }
    }

    //then, check if the current location already has a dot, if not, add one
}
```

This is all untested and just from the top of my head, but I hope you get the general gist of what I'm saying.